# Find Fixed Effects not just for intercept

Tags: r, lme4, random-effects

I am using the lmer function to gather the random effects and fixed effects. When running my function I am able to get the random effects for all coefficients by group. When I search for the fixed effects though, I only get it for the intercept. How do I get the fixed effect for all the coefficients?

Here is my example:

```
form_lmer <- "y  ~   1 + Var1 + 1 | group"
fm3<- lmer(as.formula(form_lmer), df, REML = FALSE, verbose = TRUE)
final<-ranef(fm3)
head(final)

$group
      (Intercept)                    Var1
500  0.0429171100           -0.0114512020
501 -0.0483822296            0.0793030797
502  0.0368572644           -0.0060213102
504  0.0390749512           -0.0075918832
505  0.0608323336           -0.0294764946
506  0.0030031361            0.0278525937

final2<-fixef(fm3)
final2
(Intercept) 
  0.9716914
```

I want my final output for fixed effects to be something like this:

```
new_output
(Intercept)    Var1
  0.9716914     ###
```

Comment: the normal syntax is to use parenthesis for the random effects: `(1 | group)` for random intercepts or `(var1 | group)` for correlated random slopes / intercepts. So perhaps you want `y  ~   1 + Var1 + (Var1 | group)`

Comment: when i do that though, it does give me that fixed effect output but it then removes Var1 in the random effects part

Comment: should I just do two separate lmer functions to get the two outputs?

Comment: I think the last part might do it. And then let's say I have 4 Variables, would it just be `y ~ 1 + Var1 + Var2 + Var3 + Var4 + (Var1+Var2+Var3+Var4 | group)`?

Comment: Yes, but I'd have a think about which variables should vary rather than lumping them all in.

Comment: Only asking because currently the way I would do this is by doing `y ~ 1 + Var1 + Var2 + Var3 + Var4 + (1 | group)`. But that wouldn't give me the output I want. Thanks for your help by the way

Comment: perhaps of interest : https://bbolker.github.io/mixedmodels-misc/glmmFAQ.html#model-definition

Comment: Thanks, it seems like this could be a solution then: `y ~ 1 + Var1 + Var2 + Var3 + Var4 + (1+Var1+Var2+Var3+Var4 | group)`

Comment: Also, sorry for all the questions. Just to be clear, the random effects are the residual from the fixed effect/coefficient?

Comment: I wouldn't describe them like that, but I think answering that requires stats advice (https://stats.stackexchange.com/) and I'm not the person to give it!

Comment: ok will do, thanks for the help! Mind putting your solution of `y ~ 1 + Var1 + Var2 + Var3 + Var4 + (1+Var1+Var2+Var3+Var4 | group)` as an answer to give you credit?

Comment: please feel free to write it up

Comment: Are you stating that `Var1` varies at both the individual and group level? This doesn't strike me as a realistic data collection scheme

Comment: @AlexW ; can you expend please - the OP's use of a *random slopes* model is not unusual.

Comment: @user20650 Use of RE slopes is not unusual, what is unusual is to have a parameter that is estimated at both the L1 and L2 levels (typically individuals and groups). The model is estimating that a global effect is present for `Var1` which is consistent across all individuals; but, at the same time, a random effect is present for `Var1` which varies by group. To estimate this, the data scheme would need to have variability across both individuals and groups. This strikes me as unusual

Comment: Hi @AlexW ; thanks for responding:  Sorry, I seem to be missing something: this model is common in repeat measurements / eg growth curve models. (and the `?lmer` help has several examples: `lmer(Reaction ~ Days + (Days | Subject), sleepstudy)`. These seem in line with what the op is doing.

Comment: I also found out that `lmList` works pretty well for more variables. This example worked for a small amount but took a very long time when I had about 10 or more included in the `(1+Var1+Var2....|group)`

Comment: @nak5120 ; that is a different model though - sometimes the variance components are of interest. And of course you will run into problems if a group has few observations, and again dependent on counts lower precision.

Comment: It sounds like I'm the one missing something... I don't see any reason to continue the conversational digression as long as the approach is working and valid. Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of

`y  ~   1 + Var1 + 1 | group`,

write

`y  ~   1 + Var1 + (1+Var1 | group)`.

If you have multiple variables then write it as: `y  ~   1 + Var1 + Var2 + (1+Var1+Var2 | group)`